# Get json content of request and response on annotated Spring Controller

Tags: json, spring, annotations, request, aop

I want to build a library that will save the Json content of request and response on annotated Spring controller.

So i've build my own annotation @Foo and put it on some controllers:

```
    @Foo
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/doSomeThing", produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<T> doSomething(/*some parameters*/) {
        T t = doSomeJob(T.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<T>(t, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I have no guarantee that request and response are in Contrellor's parameters!
And i'm catching the call on any Controller  having that annotation within an @AfterReturning AOP pointcut.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class XYInterceptor
@AfterReturning(
            pointcut = "execution(@my.annotation.Foo)")
            public void doSomethingWithJsonContent(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

            //How can i get json value of request and response here?    
}
```

How can I get request and response content formatted in json (such as it is send/returned to the client) ?

Thanx for your help!

Comment: Please check my answer in this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50712697/3073945

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need request and response somehow accessible from your controller method, either via an injected class member, method parameter or method return value. It has got to be ***somewhere***. Because you did not explain where you intend to get it from, I can just post a general answer showing how to determine method arguments and return value from an `@AfterReturning` advice. If you update the question with more detailed information, I can also update the answer accordingly.

My pointcut (the commented-out one also works, choose your favourite one) binds the return value to a parameter and just assumes that both request and response are of `String` type. Feel free to replace by your favourite. Furthermore, you can bind a parameter from your intercepted method (no matter where it is in the signature) to a typed advice method parameter if you know that the parameter exists and also know its (super) type. This way you can get rid of the slow and ugly loop over `getArgs()`.

```java
//@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(@my.annotation.Foo * *(..))", returning = "response")
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "@annotation(my.annotation.Foo)", returning = "response")
public void interceptRequest(String response, JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    for (Object arg : thisJoinPoint.getArgs()) {
        if (arg instanceof String)
            System.out.println("  request = " + arg);
    }
    System.out.println("  response = " + response);
}
```